# How I can Create this shape using This Div only

Tags: html, css, rotation, transform

I wanna know how to create this shape in the picture using css, I crated the same but the main div go to the back.

```html
<div>Elzero</div>
```

[check this pic please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12ufR.png)

Comment: With two pseudo elements. `:before`, `:after` absolute position, negative z-index with `transform: rotate(3deg)`. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 4em;
}

div {
  background: #eee;
  border: .1em solid #ccc;
  color: #06a9f4;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1.5em 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  background: currentColor;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -.1em;
  right: -.1em;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}

div::after {
  background: #e92a63;
  transform: rotate(8deg);
}
```

```html
<div>Elzero</div>
```